# Is $\alpha$ conjugate to $\beta$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\alpha=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1&2&3&4&5\\
2&1&4&5&3
\end{array}\right)$ then is $\alpha$  conjugate to $\beta=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1&2&3&4&5\\
2&1&4&5&3
\end{array}\right)$? How can we solve this in general too. If i give any permutations and i wish to check they are conjugates, how can i do? Help me please

Comment: Did you intend for $\alpha = \beta$ because that makes them conjugate in an obvious way:  $1 \alpha 1^{-1} = \beta$.

Comment: Each n cycle is conjugate to all other n cycles. This can also be extended. If (n) denotes an n cycle. Then each cycle having the form (n)(m) is conjugate to any other cycle havinh the form (n)(m)

Comment: Are you familiar with cycle notation for permutations?  For example, $\alpha = (1\,2)(3\,4\,5)$.

Comment: Did you notice that according to what you wrote,  $\;\alpha=\beta\;$ ?

Answer (score 3):

These two permutations are conjugate in $S_5$ because they have the same cycle structure (a 2-cycle and a 3-cycle). For example $(a\,b)(c\,d\,e)$ and $(x\,y)(u\,v\,w)$ are conjugate via $a\mapsto x$, $b\mapsto y$, $c\mapsto u$, $d\mapsto v$, $e\mapsto w$.

Comment: But in textbooks they are giving this that if there is a $g$ such that $g\alpha g^{-1}=\beta$, then only $\alpha$ is conjugate to $beta$. @Hagen

Comment: the converse is always equivalent: $g\alpha g^{-1} = \beta \Leftrightarrow \alpha = g^{-1} \beta g$. Now take $h=g^{-1}$ for the right candidate.

Comment: @David:  That is the definition, and it applies in all groups.  Hagen is correct in answering your question, how can we tell?, that two permutations are conjugate in a symmetric group if and only if they have the same (disjoint) cycle structure.  In fact it is not difficut to constrct the $g$ you want for the definition once you see the cycle structures written out.